# Scrape data from bloomberg

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from the Bloomberg website. The data under "IBVC:IND
Caracas Stock Exchange Stock Market Index" needs to be scraped.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 '
}
res = requests.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/IBVC:IND", headers=headers)

soup = bs(res.content, 'html.parser')
# print(soup)
itmes = soup.find("div", {"class": "snapshot__0569338b snapshot"})

open_ = itmes.find("span", {"class": "priceText__1853e8a5"}).text
print(open_)
prev_close = itmes.find("span", {"class": "priceText__1853e8a5"}).text
```

I can't find the required values in the HTML. Which library should I use to handle that? I'm currently using BeautifulSoup and Requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in other answers, the content is generated via JavaScript, hence not inside the plain html. For the given problem, two different angles of attack have been proposed

- `Selenium` aka *The Big Guns*: This will let you automate virtually *any* task in a browser. Comes at a certain cost though in terms of speed.
- `API Request` aka *Thought Through*: This is not always feasible. When it is however the case then it is *much* more efficient.

I elaborate on the second one. @ViniciusDAvila already laid out the typical blueprint for such a solution: navigate to the site, inspect the *Network* and figure out which request is responsible for fetching the data.

Once this is done, the rest is a matter of execution:

**Scraper**

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import quote


# Constants
HEADERS = {
    'Host': 'www.bloomberg.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}
URL_ROOT = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/datastrip'
URL_PARAMS = 'locale=en&customTickerList=true'
VALID_TYPE = {'currency', 'index'}


# Scraper
def scraper(object_id: str = None, object_type: str = None, timeout: int = 5) -> list:
    """
    Get the Bloomberg data for the given object.
    :param object_id: The Bloomberg identifier of the object.
    :param object_type: The type of the object. (Currency or Index)
    :param timeout: Maximal number of seconds to wait for a response.
    :return: The data formatted as dictionary.
    """
    object_type = object_type.lower()
    if object_type not in VALID_TYPE:
        return list()
    # Build headers and url
    object_append = '%s:%s' % (object_id, 'IND' if object_type == 'index' else 'CUR')
    headers = HEADERS
    headers['Referer'] += object_append
    url = '%s/%s?%s' % (URL_ROOT, quote(object_append), URL_PARAMS)
    # Make the request and check response status code
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code in range(200, 230):
        return response.json()
    return list()
```

**Test**

```
# Index
object_id, object_type = 'IBVC', 'index'
data = scraper(object_id=object_id, object_type=object_type)
print('The open price for %s %s is: %d' % (object_type, object_id, data[0]['openPrice']))
# The open price for index IBVC is: 50094

# Exchange rate
object_id, object_type = 'EUR', 'currency'
data = scraper(object_id=object_id, object_type=object_type)
print('The open exchange rate for USD per {} is: {}'.format(object_id, data[0]['openPrice']))
# The open exchange rate for USD per EUR is: 1.0993
```

Answer (score 2):

Since that's not a static page, you need to make a request to the Bloomberg API. To find out how, go to the page, inspect element and select "Network", then filter by "XHR" and look for JSON types. Reload the page. I did that and believe this is what you want: [link](https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/datastrip/IBVC%3AIND%2CINDU%3AIND%2CSPX%3AIND?locale=en&customTickerList=true)

Answer (score 2):

As the required values are dynamically loaded. In this case, you may try with selenium and BeautifulSoup. Here is a sample code for your reference:

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# put the driver in the folder of this code
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')  

driver.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/IBVC:IND")
time.sleep(3)
real_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
open_ = real_soup.find("span", {"class": "priceText__1853e8a5"}).text
print(f"Price: {open_}")
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Price: 50,083.00
```

You can search for chromedriver and download one based on your chrome version.