# Copied XPath returns empty result?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

Using [this webpage](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html) for testing, and this [Bloomberg page](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/ZARATHU:BZ) as a source for the XML string, I wat to get the NAV value that is in big numbers. If I inspect the element with Google Chrome and right-click to copy the XPath I get:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/section/section[2]/section/div[1]/span[1]
```

If I copy the full XPath, then I get:

```
/html/body/div[6]/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/section/section[2]/section/div[1]/span[1]
```

It would be even better if something like this worked:

```
//span[@class="priceText__1853e8a5"]
```

But all these expressions, despite being marked valid by the tool, also give an empty result in the testing tool and in my Google Spreadsheet, where I use:

```
=importxml("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/ZARATHU:BZ";"//span[@class='priceText__1853e8a5']")
```

Though I note all the queries above don't work on the spreadsheet as well.

Comment: The element with that class is not a `div` but a `span`. You probably mean `//span[@class="priceText__1853e8a5"]`. I confirm this span is in the source code of the page. If you still can't retrieve it, please include a link your Google sheet.

Comment: @derloopkat well pointed, thank you. But even then, your XPath query returns empty both on my spreadsheet and on https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html (the testing tool)

Comment: The tool you mention is for parsing xml, not html. Web pages are not standard xml, they could contain self closing tags or symbols like `<`, `>` into `script` tags that would break an xml parser and not even report the error correctly.

Comment: As I've said, if you show what you have in your Google spreadsheet may be someone else would be willing to help later on.

Comment: @derloopkat : Fair point, thanks. I've shown the code used on the google sheet, it is set to use comma as the decimal separator, so `;` separates arguments in a function call in my spreadsheet.

Comment: I just tried again this formula in a googlesheet and worked fine `=importxml("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/ZARATHU:BZ", "//span[@class='priceText__1853e8a5']")`, returned 1.5653. Yesterday it didn't work.

Comment: @derloopkat tested right now for the sake of "why not", and it didn't work for me. But I think Iamblichus' answer is at least partially correct, I access normally the website because I block javascript on it with a chrome plug-in (hence why I didn't suspect this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this website is protected against automated requests, and so it's blocking the requests from `IMPORTXML`. You can check that if you try to retrieve the full HTML:

```
=importxml("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/ZARATHU:BZ","html")
```

The returned HTML content includes the following:

> We've detected unusual activity from your computer network
> To continue, please click the box below to let us know you're not a robot.

#### Related:

- [Importxml script to access share prices from Bloomberg stopped working](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/72619939?hl=en)
- [Scrape data from bloomberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064494/scrap-data-from-bloomberg)

#### Edit:

The OP solved the issue by using [this web scraping add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/importfromweb_easy_web_scraping/278587576794):

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/ZARATHU:BZ";"//span[@class='priceText__1853e8a5']")
```

Comment: Worth noticing that IMPORTFROMWEB also accepts CSS selectors, which can help to simplify the path: 
````.priceText__1853e8a5````
Should work