# web scraping using BeautifulSoup, why the output is none?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

> the output should be:

S&P 500 INDEX

3,824.68

the project link here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
```

```
url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
```

```
name_box = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "name"})
name = str(name_box)
print(name)
```

```
price_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "price"})
price = str(price_box)
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

### What happens?

You get output `None` be cause you wont find your expected data in the response.

**Checking response, you will get this information:**

> We've detected unusual activity from your computer network. To
> continue, please click the box below to let us know you're not a
> robot.

May take a look at this [alternative](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-collect-data-from-tiktok-tutorial-ab848b40d191)

Answer (score 0):

HedgeHog is right that there is an issue with requesting the page. Here are some fixes to the scraping part of the program

```
name_box = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "companyName__99a4824b"})
name = name_box.text
print(name)
price_box = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "priceText__1853e8a5"})
price = price_box.text
print(price)
```

Comment: it sent this error:
name = name_box.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Have you gotten past the issue of Bloomberg blocking you for unusual activity? If not then maybe look at this post for getting Bloomberg stock data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070435. Does the data have to come from scraping Bloomberg? You could also scrape from google